# Does a return statement stop the recursive stack from continuing?

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm coding up a search_key algorithm for a binary search tree and am having issues. I'm traversing the binary search tree and comparing the nodes using an in-order traversal algorithm using the basic recursion technique. However, when the conditional hits (search_key == node[x]->value) and I return the node, it seems as if it still continues executing code even after I return the node and it affects the final output. Does the recursion stack continue even if it hits a return value? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: "It seems as if" - based on what evidence?

Comment: based on I added some print statements and they executed twice. When the print statement was immediately followed by a return.

Comment: We can't debug code we can't see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return` will return from the current function, but of course where you return to, in a recursive situation, is the level below, so you may need to check the result and decide what to do, and not continue searching the other side of a tree, for example.

Comment: Ah, perfect answer. There's no way to "end" the recursion stack somehow, is there?

Comment: If you are really desperate, you could perhaps throw an exception, use `longjmp` or crash your code, but in general, no, you have to return from each level, one at a time.

Comment: @ryan If the first function call returns, the "stack" ends. Note that a function call can't return if it's waiting for another function call to return, same as it can't run *any* code while it's waiting for another function call to return.

Answer (score 2):

You should post the snippet of code you're talking about.

Aside from that, if you've called your recursive function a given number of times, returning from the function would return you to the previous call of that function. A `return` statement won't stop all the prior recursive calls made from executing.